# The sorting of posts by a meta_query with two keys fails while separated as single queries it works

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I have a list of courses I try to sort. For sorting purpose I want to use two advanced custom fields. First a select field `class_day` containing the days:

```
1 : Mon
2 : Tue
3 : Wed
4 : Thu
5 : Fri
6 : Sat
7 : Sun
```

The first value is set to a number on purpose to make it easily sortable while the second label value is the one which will be echoed for display on the front end. The second field is a simple text field `class_start` with a number like e.g. `19:00`. Now I want to sort my posts by the `class_day` field and in case there are events on the same day sort those by the numerical value of the `class_start` text field. Problem is if I sort the posts only by `class_day`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'courses',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'class_day',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

or by `class_start`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'courses',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'class_start',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Each time the posts are sorted properly. One time by the day the other time by time. But if i try to merge the two with `meta_query` it doesn't work at all.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'courses',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array('key' => 'class_day'),
        array('key' => 'class_start')
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'meta_value',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

With `'relation' => 'OR'` the posts are only sorted by the day, but posts of the same day aren't sorted properly by the time in the second step. If i use `'relation' => 'AND'` i run in no match for the query at all cuz i run into the `else` case of the loop:

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
```

My goal would be to get a sorted list like:

```
Mon 13:00
Tue 12:30
Tue 16:00
Sat 12:00
```

But not:

```
Mon 13:00
Tue 16:00
Tue 12:30
Sat 12:00
```

**Update:**
The following custom query, and not using the wp_query function, did the trick:

```
$querystr = "
  SELECT wposts.* 
  FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta1, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta2
  WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta1.post_id
  AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id
  AND wpostmeta1.meta_key = 'class_day'
  AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'class_start'
  AND wposts.post_type = 'courses'
  AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
  ORDER BY wpostmeta1.meta_value ASC,
           wpostmeta2.meta_value ASC
";
```

**Update 2:**
Tiny update to the code of the first update. I've added `AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'`. To prevent drafts and other states being displayed. That way only published posts are shown and sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can only sort on 1 meta value.  A few posts (including [this SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679625/how-to-sort-multiple-wordpress-custom-field-values)) suggest adding a filter to change the order.

Add a function to your theme's `function.php` file that will replace the sort order:

```
function change_sort_order( $orderby ) {
    return str_replace('wp_posts.post_date', 'mt2.meta_value, mt1.meta_value',  $orderby);
}
```

Then use it where you want.  Make sure you remove the filter after it's used so that it doesn't stay in effect once you're done with it.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'courses',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array('key' => 'class_day'),
        array('key' => 'class_start')
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

add_filter('posts_orderby','change_sort_order');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter('posts_orderby','change_sort_order');
```

Comment: I know that snippet and also tried before, but it is not working for me. The updated part of my question i've added before is showing the wp query which is doing the trick for my setup